# JavaScript imageSlider

Tags: javascript

I would like you to check my JavaScript code and tell me what I did wrong, what I should improve, etc.

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/aatvfacf/2/)

```
(() => {

const mainSliderItems = document.querySelectorAll(".main-slider .main-slider__item"),   
      thumbnailsInner = document.querySelector(".main-thumbnails__inner"),
      thumbnailsImg = document.querySelectorAll(".main-thumbnails img"),
      prev = document.querySelector(".main-thumbnails__arrow-left"),
      next = document.querySelector(".main-thumbnails__arrow-right"),
      mobileViewportTV = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 1200px)');

let thumbOffsetWidth = thumbnailsImg[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
    translateX = 0;

class Slider {

  constructor(index) {
    this._index = index;
    this._requestAnimationFrameAndcustomEvent();
    this._assignEvents();
    this._setDataSlide();
    this._mobileViewportTV();
    this._init();
  }

  _mobileViewportTV() {
    if (mobileViewportTV.matches) {
     translateX = undefined;
    }
  }

  _setDataSlide() {
    for (let i = 0, len = thumbnailsImg.length; i < len; i++) {
     thumbnailsImg[i].dataSlide = i;
    };
  }

  _hideArrows() {
    this._index <= thumbnailsImg.length - 1 ? next.classList.remove('hide-arrow') : this._index;   
    this._index >= thumbnailsImg.length - 1 ? next.classList.add('hide-arrow') : this._index;
    this._index <= 0 ? prev.classList.add('hide-arrow') : this._index;
    this._index > 0 ? prev.classList.remove('hide-arrow') : this._index;
  }

  _hideAllImages(i) {
    mainSliderItems[i].classList.add('main-slider__item_hide');
  }

  _removeAllActiveClasses(i) {
    thumbnailsImg[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  _showOneImage() {
    mainSliderItems[this._index].classList.remove('main-slider__item_hide');
  }

  _addOneActiveClass() {
    thumbnailsImg[this._index].classList.add('active');
  }

  _init() {
    for (let i = 0, len = mainSliderItems.length; i < len; i++) {
      this._hideAllImages(i);
      this._removeAllActiveClasses(i);
    }
    this._showOneImage();
    this._addOneActiveClass();
    this._hideArrows();
  }

  _moveImagesToRight() {
     translateX -= thumbOffsetWidth;     
     thumbnailsInner.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  }

  _moveImagesToLeft() {
     translateX += thumbOffsetWidth;
     thumbnailsInner.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  }

  _setClicked(i) {
    thumbnailsImg[i].clicked = 'yes';
  }

  _deleteClicked(i) {
    thumbnailsImg[i].clicked = '';
  }

  _resetAllClicked() {
    for(let i = 0, len = thumbnailsImg.length; i < len; i++) {
      thumbnailsImg[i].clicked = '';
    }
  }     

  _moveImagesAfterClick() {   
    if(this._index >= 5 && this._index < 9 && thumbnailsImg[this._index].clicked !== 'yes') {
       this._setClicked(this._index);
       this._moveImagesToRight();
       if(this._index >= 5) {
          this._setClicked(this._index - 4);
       }
    } else if(this._index <= 4 && this._index >= 1 && thumbnailsImg[this._index].clicked === 'yes') {
       this._deleteClicked(this._index);
       this._moveImagesToLeft();
       if(this._index <= 4) {
          this._deleteClicked(this._index + 4);
       }
    }
    this._init();
  }

  _changeImages(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('.main-thumbnails__arrow-right')) {
       this._index >= thumbnailsImg.length - 1 ? this._index : this._index++;
       if (this._index >= 5 && this._index < 9 && thumbnailsImg[this._index].clicked !== 'yes') {   
          this._moveImagesToRight();
          this._setClicked(this._index);
          if(this._index >= 5) {
            this._setClicked(this._index - 4);
          }
       }
    } else if (e.target.matches('.main-thumbnails__arrow-left')) {
       this._index <= 0 ? this._index : this._index--;
       if (this._index <= 4 && this._index >= 1 && thumbnailsImg[this._index].clicked === 'yes') {
          this._moveImagesToLeft();
          this._deleteClicked(this._index);
          if(this._index <= 4) {
            this._deleteClicked(this._index + 4);
         }
       }
    }
    this._init();
  }

  _clickImage(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
      const x = e.target.dataSlide;
      this._index = x;
      this._moveImagesAfterClick();
    }
  }

  _assignEvents() {
    thumbnailsInner.offsetParent.addEventListener('click', this._changeImages.bind(this), false);
    thumbnailsInner.offsetParent.addEventListener('click', this._clickImage.bind(this), false);
    window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", this._resetProperties.bind(this), false);
  }

  _resetProperties() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
        thumbOffsetWidth = thumbnailsImg[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        translateX = 0;
        thumbnailsInner.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
        this._index = 0;
        this._resetAllClicked();
        this._init();
      } else {
        thumbnailsInner.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
        translateX = undefined;
        this._index = 0;
        this._resetAllClicked();
        this._init();
      }
    }

  _requestAnimationFrameAndcustomEvent() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
      obj = obj || window;
      var running = false;
      var func = function() {
          if (running) { return; }
          running = true;
           requestAnimationFrame(function() {
              obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
              running = false;
          });
      };
      obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };
    throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
  }

}

const slide = new Slider(0);

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Very neat project! I'm especially impressed by how well it handles resizing.

1. Don't leak state. What happens if you want to use the `Slider` class on two image sliders? Well, right now you can't since the elements it uses aren't saved per instance.
2. Looking at your demo, the code requires a LOT of boilerplate. The biggest area for improvement is the thumbnails -- Using different image urls for the thumbnails doesn't actually save any bandwidth so I would drop them and simply used a resized version of the full image. The thumbnail html can then be created by the class when initializing the slider.
3. Don't avoid `if` statements at the fault of making the code harder to read.

   ```js
   // This is much harder to read
   this._index <= thumbnailsImg.length - 1 ? next.classList.remove('hide-arrow') : this._index;
   // Than this
   if (this._index < thumbnailsImg.length) { next.classList.remove('hide-arrow') }
   ```
4. Without looking hard at the code, why does `_hideAllImages` accept a parameter? If it only hides one image, wouldn't it be better named `hideImage`? The same can be said for `_removeAllActiveClasses`.
5. `_moveImagesAfterClick` uses a lot of magic numbers. It would be great to remove them to make the code more flexible.
6. You may want to consider not hiding the arrows when on the last element, and looping to the first / last element on the slider if they are used to go "out of bounds"
7. Don't define functionality you don't use. The `throttle` function in `_requestAnimationFrameAndcustomEvent` accepts an `obj` parameter which is never used. At the very least `obj` should be removed. I'm not convinced that this code even needs to be in a helper method of it's own, however. The name `_requestAnimationFrameAndcustomEvent` could also use some work. Right now it describes two function that the method calls, but not what the method *does*.
8. Avoid duplicate code. `_resetProperties` could be written like this without changing the functionality at all.

   ```js
   _resetProperties() {
     if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
       thumbOffsetWidth = thumbnailsImg[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
       translateX = 0;
     } else {
       translateX = undefined;
     }
     thumbnailsInner.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;
     this._index = 0;
     this._resetAllClicked();
     this._init();
   }
   ```

There is certainly more comments that I could make regarding the structure of the class (there's a lot of hopping between methods to figure out what is going on), but if you start with these improvements your code should become cleaner.

Sidenote: It may not be within scope for this project, but this is a great example of what could be a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components).